# How to retrieve data from two tables (one-to-many) created through Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I got this html form with multi selectable checkboxes -  `details.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <div class="check">
                    <label>Addons:</label>
    
                    <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off First service visit" id="10%off First service visit">
                    <label for="10%off First service visit">10%off First service visit</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="10%off Waterwash"  id="10%off Waterwash">
                    <label for="10%off Waterwash">10%off Waterwasht</label>

                    <input type="checkbox" name ="SelectedCheckboxes[]" value="Free AC Inspection" id="Free AC Inspection">
                    <label for="Free AC Inspection">Free AC Inspection</label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Posting the input values to Web API on submit through JavaScript and created a model class in the Web API - `CarForm.cs`:

```cs
public class CarForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Selection> SelectedCheckboxes { get; set; }
}
```

`CarDbContext.cs`:

```cs
namespace CarServiceFormApi.Db
{
    public class CarDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CarDbContext(DbContextOptions<CarDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Selection> Selections { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Selection.cs`:

```cs
public class Selection
{
    public int SelectionId { get; set; }
    public string SelctionName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```cs
namespace CarServiceFormApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CarServiceFormController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CarDbContext _db;
        private static List<CarForm> CarDataList = new List<CarForm>();

        public CarServiceFormController(CarDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpPost("submit-form")]
        public IActionResult SubmitForm([FromForm] CarForm formsData)
        {
            // process the form data
            List<Selection> selectedCheckboxes = formsData.SelectedCheckboxes;

            // add the data to the database
            var carForm = new CarForm
            {
                SelectedCheckboxes= selectedCheckboxes,
            };

            _db.CarForms.Add(carForm);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            CarDataList.Add(carForm);

            return Ok(carForm);
        }

        [HttpGet("get-form-data")]
        public IActionResult GetFormData()
        {
            var data = _db.CarForms.ToList();
            return Ok(data);
        }
    }
}
```

I also got some other inputs in html, they all work fine except these Checkboxes. Since I pass them as an array, I had to create another table and joined them before "Add-migrations". I'm pretty sure that I gotta change something in my controller in order to retrieve data from SQL tables but couldn't figure out "how to".

Can someone guide me?

Comment: What does `I had to create another table and joined them before "Add-migrations"` mean? I don't know what you want from your question, Do you mean you use `_db.CarForms.ToList();` can't retrieve the whole `CarForm` with `SelectedCheckboxes` value from database?

Comment: @XinranShen sorry for the chaos, I will be posting a new question with updated code to reduce confusion and what I was trying to say is like I had to create 2 models to store the checkbox array on posting it from html. I didnt have to say that but still jus to make it clear

Comment: You mean in `SubmitForm` action you need to create 2 models to add the data from html into database? But I don't get your point from your code.

Comment: @XinranShen I  created 2 models(CarForm and Selection) right? so yea I was talking about that

Comment: Yes, you create CarForm and Selection models in your web api, but what's the problem here? EF core needs entities to manipulate data in database, If you don't have related entities, How will you use ef core?